# Automatically load a view from the controller after a timer in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Basically, what I am attempting to do is create a Slideshow. The reason why I am using Angular for this is to get the benifits from templating and hopefully load only one template to the page at a time.

I have my data in a JSON file which the controller gets:

**JSON:**

```
{
    "prop_title"    : "Hyde Lane, Hyde",
    "prop_postcode" : "SP2 7AP",
    "prop_price"    : "",
    "prop_image"    : "",
    "prop_desc"     : "",
    "template"      : "views/prop-thumbs.html",
    "info_image"    : "",
    "duration"      : "4000"

},
```

**Controller:**

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {

    //GET THE JSON FILE
    $http.get('json/pages.json').success(function (data) {

        //ASSIGN THE PAGES TO THE SCOPE
        $scope.pages = data;

        //LOOP THROUGH THE DATA AND ASSIGN THE VIEW
        for (var i = $scope.pages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        };

    });
}
```

As you can see from my JSON file, each element contains the view file to use, and the duration that it needs to stay on screen for. Also, as you can see in my controller, I have begun creating a for loop that will hopefully contain my code that will assign view on a timer. Is this possible? Whats the easiest and best way to do this?

Any help seriously appreciated, I have pretty tried everything now!

Comment: "I have pretty tried everything now!"  I suggest you show us what you've tried (at least one example).  The answer will likely involve using $timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Mark Rajcok pointed in the comments, you will probably need to use a $timeout
Here is what I would have done : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/zbg57/

The html part is quite simple, I just tell angular to include what is in the `whatToInclude` variable :

```
<div ng-include='whatToInclude'></div>
```

On the controller side, I initialize the data with a template and a counter, then I define a nextSlide function, which will call the next template with the timeout passed in parameter. I call this function to start the loop with the initials parameter (0s timeout, first element of the data)

```
$scope.whatToInclude='tpl1.html';
$scope.count=0;
$scope.nextSlide=function(timeOut){
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.whatToInclude=$scope.data[$scope.count].template
        $scope.count+=1
        if($scope.count>=$scope.data.length)
            $scope.count=0
        $scope.nextSlide($scope.data[$scope.count].duration)
    },timeOut);
};

$scope.nextSlide(0)
```

I think this can be a good start for a slideshow ;)

Have fun

Comment: Great, this looks like it does what I want it to do, however, I am getting an error when I add it to my project: 

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/main.js:17:43
    at <error: illegal access>
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3041:10)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3327:7

Comment: I think this is because of the data, if you asynchronously get it in the controller it might not be loaded when launching the first time `$scope.nextSlide(0)`, to avoid this, you can call the `$scope.nextSlide(0)` only after the load of the JSON (for example, in a success callback if it's a $http.get)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, seems to still be an issue though, I have added the $scope.nextSlide(0) into the success of my $http.get but I still receive the same error?

Comment: Ok, ignore that, I have found the issue, I was actually assigning the JSON to $scope.pages rather than $scope.data (which is what the code uses). Thanks for all your help, works great now!

Comment: EDIT : Ok I'm a bit late, glad it helped you ;) -----  Without seeing your actual code, it could be anything, but I'd invite you to check if the variable names are well written and if the objects you try to access are created. It seems I used `$scope.data` in my code, but you had `$scope.pages`, check if you replaced every occurrence, and try to do something like `console.log(any object)` in order to check if your object is defined and contains the right data

Answer (score 1):

I made a tutorial with a similar goal in mind:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9COtsDovNpM

Basically store the views in an array of some sort and then based on a variable display that template.  Angular will not load the template until ng-show='true' so they won't load all at once but as their clicked or cycled through.

Code example from my tutorial.
Replace ng-switch with whatever works for you.

The common premise is "show this template when that is equal to true".

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="{active: main.active.tab == 'info'}">
            <a ng-click='main.active.tab = "info"'>Settings</a>
        </li>

        <li ng-class="{active: main.active.tab == 'categories'}">
            <a ng-click='main.active.tab = "categories"'>Categories</a>
        </li>

        <li ng-class="{active: main.active.tab == 'pages'}">
            <a ng-click='main.active.tab = "pages"'>Pages</a>
        </li>

        <li ng-class="{active: main.active.tab == 'locations'}">
            <a ng-click='main.active.tab = "locations"; main.locationgroup = {}'>Locations</a>
        </li>

        <li ng-class="{active: main.active.tab == 'experts'}">
            <a ng-click='main.active.tab = "experts";'>Experts</a>
        </li>

        <li ng-class="{active: main.active.tab == 'resources'}">
            <a ng-click='main.active.tab = "resources"'>Resources</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div ng-switch='main.active.tab'>
            <div
                ng-switch-when='info'
                ng-include='"/apps/series/views/tabs/info.html"'></div>

            <div
                ng-switch-when='categories'
                ng-include='"/apps/series/views/tabs/categories.html"'></div>

            <div
                ng-switch-when='pages'
                ng-include='"/apps/series/views/tabs/pages.html"'></div>

            <div
                ng-switch-when='locations'
                ng-include='"/apps/series/views/tabs/locations.html"'></div>

            <div
                ng-switch-when='experts'
                ng-include='"/apps/series/views/tabs/experts.html"'></div>

            <div
                ng-switch-when='resources'
                ng-include='"/apps/series/views/tabs/resources.html"'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```